# How to search the specific text in a nested object?

Tags: javascript, json

For example, I have a JSON array as follow, I will show it on a treelist ,so that user can select the item.Now there is a feature that allowing the user to search the specific text in the list. And the list is a nested list.I hava bind the JSON array to a treelist using HTML and Javascript. Now I should find a good way to search the specific text, and then return the object that include parent node when I find the text.

```
var allcategories=
[
{
    "name": "shoes",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "name": "man's shoes",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "sample name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sample name",
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "woman's shoes",
            "subcategories": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "cars",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "name": "cars1",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "sample name"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sample name",
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
];
```

So now I want to use the `indexOf()` function to search the result. If the search is successful, the program should just return the parent category.Anyone have the same question in developing the codes?

Comment: Search the result for _what_?

Comment: If you just need the parent category, don't use a deeply nested datastructure? Of course, you always can recurse it…

Comment: What you got so far? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @RobG I can get the results from the first object, but I can't get the result form the second json object.

Comment: And your code to get the result from the first object is…?

Comment: I would suggest since you are already working with json to use a plugin for the tree which has selective functions built in. I have found http://www.jstree.com/ is great.

Comment: @vikingben I want to use a TreeList plugin for my project. But the items of treelist should be drag and drop,so I writing a simple treelist for my project. I will try to use jstree plugin in next version. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bergi suggests, you can use a recursive function:

```
  function getCategory(categories, name) {
    var category, result;

    for (var i=0, iLen=categories.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      category = categories[i];

      if (category.name == name) {
        return category;

      } else if (category.subcategories) {
        result = getCategory(category.subcategories, name);

        if (result) return result;
      }
    }
    // return undefined if category name not found
  }
```

Note that this will return the first subcategory with a matching name, so the name needs to be unique.

Comment: I think we should not using "return" in the program, we can use an array to store the result. Because we may get a lot of "object" result. And I find this program cannot return the json object which is the parent node including the specific text I find. But thank you so much, you give me a good idea.My final codes as follow.

Answer (score 0):

@Leeli - you can use this JS lib; DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) with which searches in JSON structures becomes a trivial thing. The lib extends the global object JSON with the method "search". With this method, you can search with XPath expressions and it will retusn an array with the matches (empty array if no matches were found). See the example code below.

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/wXfE6/

```
var data = [
       {
          "name": "shoes",
          "subcategories": [
             {
                "name": "man's shoes",
                "subcategories": [
                   { "name": "heels" },
                   { "name": "loafers" }
                ]
             },
             { "name": "woman's shoes" }
          ]
       },
       {
          "name": "cars",
          "subcategories": {
             "name": "cars1",
             "subcategories": [
                { "name": "Sedan" },
                { "name": "SUV" }
             ]
          }
       }
    ],
    res = JSON.search( data, '//*[name="cars1"]/subcategories' );

console.log( res[0].name );
// Sedan
```

Answer (score 0):

hi here is a jquery function i wrote. since its a associated list in .net the child list is an empty object when there are no child nodes so i have to check is empty instead of simply looking for it to be null. should be backwards compatible though and work as a solution to this question

```
function findCategory(categories, categoryId)
    {
        var ret = null;
        $.each(categories, function (e, v) {
            if (e === categoryId)
                ret = v;
            else if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(v.children))
                ret = findCategory(v.children, categoryId);
            return !ret; //break out of loop when ret not null
        });
        return ret;
    }
```